# Servlet inside a JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a Servlet inside a JSP that display an image

```
<img id='225926' 
       src='http://127.0.0.1:7001/mindfulness/displayLogo?  
          resize=true&height=100' align='bottom' />
```

The servlet:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                        throws IOException, ServletException {

            System.out.println  ("DisplayImageServlet : "); 
            ...
}
```

But it seems that when I push the back button in the browser, the servlet is not called again and I see the previous image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a browser cache issue. One common solution to this would be to generate a random number and append it as a request parameter to the servlet URL. The servlet can ignore the paramter, but this should make the URL unique and therefore uncacheable